# login from scrapy when website has captcha

Tags: python, scrapy, captcha

I need extract data from website with scrapy but before anything I should login.
login page has a captcha, so What should I do ?

website : [tinyz.us](http://tinyz.us)

username field:

```
<input class="en" name="login_user" type="text">
```

username field:

```
<input class="en" name="login_password" type="password">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try first through Optical Character Recognition (OCR) and then with a
CAPTCHA solving API. See the chapter 7 of this book: https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/web-scraping-python

There are also on-line services to solve captcha. For example:
https://anti-captcha.com/